# How to pass function to the setInterval?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this function:

```
function executeCommand(callback) {
    let params = {screen_name: '...'};
    client.get('/statuses/user_timeline', params, function(error, tweets) {
        if (JSON.parse(tweets[0].text).ip === 'all'){
            exec(JSON.parse(tweets[0].text).command, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return;
                }
                return callback(stdout);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I want to call it with timeout. I know about `setInterval`, but how to pass my `executeCommand()` to it?

I tried like that but it doesn't work:

```
setInterval(executeCommand(function(resp){console.log(resp)}), 3000);` .
```

P.S calling of `executeCommand` looks like:

```
executeCommand(function(resp){console.log(resp)})
```

Is it possible to do call like that:

```
console.log(executeCommand())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your first try, is that you're passing the response of your `executeCommand` as parameter, not the function itself. I recommend you try this:

```
setInterval(() => {
    executeCommand(function(resp){console.log(resp)});
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're currently immediately executing it which makes the function run and return `undefined` (why undefined? because that is the default return value of a function that doesn't explicitly return anything else), so every 3sec you get undefined, to fix that you could wrap it in an anonymous function like this:

```
setInterval(() => executeCommand(resp => console.log(resp)), 3000)
```

Comment: i suppose you pass excess 3000

Answer (score 2):

Just bind the argument:

```
setInterval(executeCommand.bind(null, console.log), 1000)
```

Comment: or even `setInterval(executeCommand, 1000, console.log)` some browsers may need `console.log` itself to be bound but nowadays they normally don't.